# check if variable contains the output of a string for multiple values in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
output=`sql -c "show sca_mode"` # ----> [ NOTICE:  SCA_MODE is off
                                #                         SHOW VARIABLE]
```

it might show **on or off** as per variable set.

i want to display if sca_mode=true then copy abc.exp_scamode_true file  and if SCA_MODE is off then abc.exp_scamode_file

if i am executing below command :

```
[bin]$ if [[ "$output" = *on* ]]; then sca_mode=true ;else sca_mode=false; fi
[bin]$ echo $output
 SHOW VARIABLE
```

i am not getting "on" or "off" value rather its showing the last row

Comment: What does `sql -c "show sca_mode"` actually emit? Have you checked for whether it's emitting terminal control characters, like `\r`s (causing the cursor to go back and overwrite prior contents)?

Comment: Try `echo "$output" | less`; is the result any different?

Comment: Echo $output = SHOW VARIABLE. ( Ommiting first line).
sql -c = c is for run only single query. This is kind of alias setup for our project. 

Analysis:
variable is False
[bin]$ output=`sql -c "show sca_mode"` 
Result= SCA_MODE is off
[bin]$ if [[ "$output" =~ "on" ]]; then sca_mode=true ;else echo sca_mode=false; fi
 Result== sca_mode=false
[bin]$  if [[ $sca_mode =~ "true"  ]]  then echo "correct"; else  echo "incorrect" ; fi
Result== incorrect
Then I changed the varibale to True. ran same 3 cmnds,  showing the incorrect  excpt first 1. Other two cmds show as above result